# Why my stripe elements are causing error?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have been stuck on this for 3 days. I am trying to create a payment gateway using stripe. And I followed their documentation carefully. But can't figure out what is the problem.
App.js

```
function App() {
  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState("");
  const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_51Nlrg3SBPgnIenaraTXJCnFylotLWkZolX6UcTCSnEUN3YEfHfNsio6IVdQ8ZzE53hUwUWrtiQZkz0yyfD6IvZky00nbAYVr2F');
  async function getStripeApiKey() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/v1/stripeapikey");
    setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
store.dispatch(loadUser());
getStripeApiKey()
  }, []);
  
  
  return (
    <Router>    
      <Routes>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/process/payment"
        element={
          stripeApiKey && (
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                <Payment />
              </Elements>
          )}/>
</Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I tried with providing the stripe key manually and also supplied from backend. But getting the error *"invalid prop `stripe` supplied to `elements`. we recommend using the `loadstripe` utility from `@stripe/stripe-js`. see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-props-stripe for details."*
This is my Payment file

```
return (
<form className='paymentForm' onSubmit={(e)=>submitHandler(e)}>
        <Typography>Card Info</Typography>
        <div>
            <CreditCardIcon/>       
            <CardNumberElement className='paymentInput'/> 
        </div>
    </form> )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be loading Stripe in your main React file as following:

```
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

// Make sure to call loadStripe outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the Stripe object on every render.
// This is your test publishable API key.
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_51LFx4JF1SIVBSMvIiQmcLaJqQkmWpPi0EPxrVdMyslzvPbh9Hu77WZTnbBp9p46zXlJa2MRt8HpZsT6jVNraOmjw00ZirV6oRo");
```

I invite you to follow this [complete quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?platform=web&client=react&lang=node) in order to integration Stripe with ReactJs